# How to use Particle Swarm Optimization calling a function from a script

Tags: matlab, function, particle-swarm

I want to use PSO in the following structure:

```
lb = [-10,-15];
ub = [15,20];
options = optimoptions('particleswarm','SwarmSize',100,'HybridFcn',@fmincon);
rng default  % For reproducibility
nvars = 2;

x = particleswarm(fun,nvars,lb,ub)
```

Where fun is saved in other script with the following structure

```
function y = fun(x)

y = x(1)*exp(-norm(x)^2);
end
```

But it is not working. I can see that PSO work if I save fun in the same code:

```
lb = [-10,-15];
ub = [15,20];
fun = @(x)x(1)*exp(-norm(x)^2);
options = optimoptions('particleswarm','SwarmSize',100,'HybridFcn',@fmincon);
rng default  % For reproducibility
nvars = 2;
x = particleswarm(fun,nvars,lb,ub)
```

But this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for applying swarm in a function saved in another script.
How could I make PSO work in this sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `@`:

```
x = particleswarm(@fun,nvars,lb,ub)
```

This makes sure that you are giving the optimizer the handle to the function `fun`, and not evaluate the function without any input parameters. See the Matlab [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) on function handles.